# Defining a list of error messages and error codes

Tags: python, exception

I want to create a list (not implying Python `List`) of error messages and corresponding error codes. I have two requirements - *be able to look up the error message given an error code* and *be able to perform the opposite look-up*.

1. Is there a native python data type that can achieve this? If not, how should I implement this?
2. This list of error messages + codes would be used by BusinessRuleViolation, a custom exception class. I want this list to associate with BusinessRuleViolation and shouldn't be modified during runtime. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to find an error code given the error message? Where does the message come from?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - The error message, code, and the association between message and code are all self-defined. The error message would be used by a custom exception class, BusinessRuleViolation. I am planning to use the error codes to retrieve their corresponding error messages for me to use `assertRaisesRegexp` in unit testing.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Just to add to my previous comment. I am taking this approach because I know the wording of the error messages will be changed later on, as I am not willing to spend time on worrying about the wording of them at this moment.

Comment: Then simply do not use error messages in your code but instead short descriptive messages. And if need be to display then to user then you can always feth full version of messages via gettext, or similar mechanisms (localization mechanisms have many unorthodox usages :) )

Comment: @przemo_li - I think you got ahead of me. At this stage, I simply don't want to worry about designing app errors. But what I do need is seeing custom exceptions being raised when I expect them to (speaking of unit testing business logic). As a result, all I need now is a collection of static error codes and dynamic but meaningful  error messages. Having that said, your suggestion is great, which I might consider down the road.

Comment: Oh! Hmm they why do not you just structure your exceptions into inheritance hierarchy? With default messages, and method that return formated default string with values passed on creation. This way, you do not need ugly hacks, you just compare in your unit tests to default string, and when you need detailed info it is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you'd do this with a pair of `dict`s - one mapping error codes to messages, and then another one (often programmatically generated) with the reverse mapping.

```
error_codes_to_messages = {
   1: 'foo',
   2: 'bar',
   3: 'baz',
}

error_messages_to_codes = dict(
    (v,k) for k,v in error_codes_to_messages.iteritems()
)
```

Then you can do lookups with `[]`:

```
print error_codes_to_messages[2]
print error_messages_to_codes['foo']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Amber. It looks great. As to the 2) of my problem, is it right to implement `error_codes_to_messages` as part of the BusinessRuleViolation class and change the name to `ERROR_CODES_TO_MESSAGES` to denote that it shouldn't be changed?

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just have a collection of error code objects, since it is highly unlikely that this will be a performance bottleneck:

```
errors = [Error1, Error2, Error3, ...]

def lookupError(number=None, text=None, matcher=None, multiple=False):
    if number!=None:
        matcher = lambda x:x.number==number
    if text!=None:
        matcher = lambda x:text in x.text

    results = [e for e in errors if matcher(e)]
    if multiple:
        return results
    else:
        assert len(results)==1, 'Error lookup failed, expected one error but got {}'.format(results)
        return results[0]
```

Usage:

```
>>> lookupError(number=5)
>>> lookupError(text='index')
>>> lookupError(matcher=lambda x:x.context==StartupSequence)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't need "error message" -> "error code" mapping. You could create an exception class that contains both error code and message. It would allow to localize messages without breaking any code in the future.

For example, `OSError` has `errno`, `strerror` attributes that contain an error code and message correspondingly.

To catch errors more conveniently you could create subclasses for frequently used error codes e.g., `OSError` has subclasses such as `PermissionError`, `FileNotFoundError`:

```
try:
    open(somefile)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # handle file not found error
except PermissionError:
    # handle permission problem
```

Python is a dynamic language so it is easy to generate the exception classes programmatically from whatever current representation you use for error codes, messages.